# How to make json_encode fail

Tags: php, json, testing

Trying to test a method that is doing a `json_encode` and throwing an exception if the encode fails. However, whatever I throw at `json_encode` it successfully encodes. Any idea what would be something simple to have it fail?

Comment: Encode a resource like a database connection? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: Or arrays with depth >= 512, or non-valid L1 control characters (0x80-0x9F)

Comment: I thought json_encode just returns null if the input is invalid. I could be wrong.

Comment: @CMiller json_encode by default returns null on invalid input but will place an error in `json_last_error`. The library that I am using (Guzzle) wraps json_encode and trows an exception when invalid input is given.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the smallest values to fail `json_encode` would be:

```
json_encode(NAN);
json_encode(INF);
```

Other candidate:

```
$a = array(&$a);
json_encode($a);
```

Answer (score 7):

```php
$text = "\xB1\x31";

$json  = json_encode($text);
```

For checking errors you can use [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php).